# facebook app does not show turn off https

Tags: facebook

I create a simple facebook app, and when users with https navigate to that, the dialog that alert them about turning off https, does not appear. just a blank page shown and nothing else. can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Check you application settings under **Settings**->**Basic** "*App on Facebook*".

There is option "**Secure Canvas URL**".

This is the url that you application is redirected when users are using HTTPS.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, and this url must refer to what? a secure page on my site or a url to requesting user to turn off https? can you explain more please?

Comment: Yes, you must have "https://" .. URL adress of your app. This is what Facebook says about this: "Contrary to some feedback we’ve heard, acquiring an SSL certificate is relatively inexpensive, and the ongoing cost of supporting SSL for most apps is low. The sooner your app supports HTTPS the more secure our platform will become. All Apps on Facebook (Canvas and Page Tabs) must support HTTPS by October 1." You can obtain SSL sertificate for example from http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx?isc=sslqeur06&currencytype=EUR or http://www.verisign.com/ssl/